# Where should I locate an exhaust fan in a 110 square foot bathroom with an included 15 square foot toilet room

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, ventilation

I have a 110 square foot bathroom with a 12 foot ceiling.  There is an included toilet room 15 feet square with an 8 foot ceiling  with what is probably a 50cfm exhaust fan in the ceiling.  I want to have sufficient ventilation for the entire bathroom to remove moisture when showering.  Would it work to replace the 50 cfm a 100+ cfm fan in the toilet room and keep the door open when showering?  Or should I install a second fan in the 12 foot ceiling?

Comment: Fan size is determined by how many room air exchanges do you need.

Answer (score 1):

With your numbers you will only get 4.3 air exchanges per hour. That is on low end for bathrooms, it should be more like 10 air exchanges per hour.

First determine the room volume by multiplying the square area by hight. 115 x 12 = 1380.

Then convert the cfm to cf/hour (x60) 100x60 = 6,000

Now divide 6000 by 1380 = 4.3 air exchanges per hour

Better would be to have 200 cfm fan to get 10 air exchanges per hour or one every 6 minutes.

Comment: To clarify my question, is it your opinion that one 200 cfm fan mounted in the toilet room with door open to the main bathroom area would be as effective as installing a second fan in the main bathroom area?  For instance, would a 50 cfm toilet room fan plus a 150 cfm main area fan result in the same AE/hour rate as a single 200 cfm fan in the toilet room with door open?